# Error at execution without reaching my code

Tags: c#, .net

I would post my code, but I don't see the point, since if I put a breakpoint in it, it never reaches it, the error is triggered before the execution reaches it. I initially thought it could have been a duplicate in the .config file, but I haven't seen any. The code compiles properly.

Thanks.

Here is the error I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has alr
eady been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boo
lean add)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.AddKey(TKey key, TItem it
em)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2.InsertItem(Int32 index, T
Item item)
   at NDesk.Options.OptionSet.InsertItem(Int32 index, Option item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at NDesk.Options.OptionSet.Add(String prototype, String description, Action`1
 action)
   at manifest_mass_deployment.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Edit: The error was related to NDESK, I was using the same variable twice:

```
var p = new OptionSet(){
  { "t|time=", "start time", v=> starttime = v },
  { "s|span=", "span time", v=> spantime = v },
  { "t|thread=", "Fhreads to fork", v=> threads = v },
}
```

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: What is your question and how do you expect the community to help you?

Comment: You dont see the point posting your code? Thats fine, I dont see the point in trying to answer. Moving on....

Comment: Flagged to close. If you're not going to submit the code causing the issue then its not a fit for the expected Question format.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint at the first line of code, it never reaches it. It crashes before. Wouldn't this mean the code is not the source of the error?

Comment: What's `NDesk`? As this is causing the problem, maybe you should check into what it is doing on startup?

Comment: @Jamie Keeling , can you remove the close flag. This issue is quite dumb, but tricky, and I can others having it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises with `NDesk`. If this is the *callback-based program option parser for C#* found [here](http://www.ndesk.org/Options), maybe it does something before your code runs? Maybe it tries to parse command line options?

At least, the message is clear: `NDesk` is trying to add a key to a dictionary which already exists. If this is nothing in your code, it must be some automatic mechanism that for example reads a file and builds a dictionary from it.

From what I see, `NDesk` should help you parse command line options - the problem may be that you're passing in the same parameter twice?

Comment: Exactly this. Was parsing "t" twice. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are adding an item to a collection that already contains an item with the same key. Keynames have to be unique.

Comment: collection, or Dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary is a collection

Comment: All dictionaries might be collections, but all collections are not dictionaries.

Comment: Dictionaries are not the only collections containing keys.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty self explanatory. You are trying to add a key that already exists.  Visual Studio will probably highlight the line where this is happening.

If it is not, then you can try altering the configuration that might be causing the issue, or begin debugging from the application run code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is duplicate startup arguments to your program. Check `Project Properties -> Debug -> Command Line Arguments`.

Comment: there is nothing in the command line arguments.

Comment: Ok, well post the contents of your `main` method, the issue is with a duplicate item being added to `NDesk.Options`

Answer (score 0):

`An item with the same key has already been added.`

I think it is exactly as it sounds. You are populating a dictionary and adding the same key twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a situation where breakpoints aren't hit because Visual Studio has got overexcited and started cacheing a file that it shouldn't be. You could try making sure you clean your solution before rebuilding. If that doesn't work try deleting the contents of `[BootDir]:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Temp` and if you're working with an Asp.Net solution `[BootDir]:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[FrameworkVersion]\Temporary ASP.NET Files` - those should purge any files that Visual Studio is saving for itself.